# Is there something like "spin" or "darken" "ligher" functions in Compass CSS like LESS has

Tags: css, less, compass-sass, sass

I was using LESS css and loved the ability to generate dynamic color schemes with it using functions like spin, darken, fade, saturate etc... and now i am using compass but am unable to find any similar functions in Compass CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the Sass color functions, Compass has [color helpers](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/colors/).

- adjust lightness
- adjust saturation
- scale lightness
- scale saturation
- shade
- tint

Answer (score 6):

You can use the adjust_hue, adjust_saturation & adjust_brightness functions.

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adjust_color-instance_method